# How to show how many people have signed up on my website?

Tags: javascript, python, forms, web, flask

I have an HTML form that asks users for their emails, and a .txt file where the emails are stored line by line. How do I show on my website, a "counter", like so:

"Join x number of people who already signed up!"

Where x is an int that counts the number of emails in the .txt file? I am using `flask` for my web server, combined with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: Get the number of emails with the following: `emails_count = sum(1 for line in open('members.txt'))`, change members.txt to your file dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route that serves the signup form, read the file line by line, find the length of the resulting list, and pass the result to `flask.render_template`:

`signup.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>     
    <p> Join {{num}} other user{{plural}} who have already signed up!</p>
    <form action = '/get_data' method='POST'> 
      <input type='email' name='email' placeholder='enter your email'>
      <input type='submit'>Submit</input>  
    </form>
  <body>
</html>
```

In the route:

```
@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET'])
def signup():
   current_users = len([i for i in open('filename.txt')])
   return flask.render_template('signup.html', num = current_users, plural = '' if current_users == 1 else 's')

@app.route('/get_data', methods=['POST'])
def get_email():
   with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
     f.write('{}\n'.format(flask.request.form["email"]))
   return '<h1>Thanks!</h1>'
```

Comment: It worked beautifully! Thank you so much good sir :)

Comment: @EvanYang Glad to help!